# How to get total points in Microsoft quiz using Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, power-automate-desktop

I would like to get total points(score) every time a quiz is submitted using Power Automate.
However, I can only get the answers to each question but not the total score.[image]

Is there a way to get the total points just like the Excel from the webpage?
[image]
[image]